# How to make the build process not compile all .scss files into a main.css

Tags: css, sass, ionic3

All my various components have some .scss files which get eventually merged into a single main.css This make it hard to debug as the Chrome Developer Console has no back-references to the source scss like for example, component1.scss

For debugging-run purposes is it possible to keep the various .scss files separate unmodified?

Consider the following snapshot from the Chrome Dev. Console, I can guess where a style like ChannelEntryComp is coming from, but I am clueless about a style like "label", "input",
Perhaps, they may have been redefined in different .scss in my project, intentionally or not, and thus side-effecting the net result.

[image]

Here is my current build command line for the browser build, are there parameters I could specify here or elsewhere?:

```
ionic serve --no-open --allow-file-access-from-files --target cordova
```

Just when I think I understand CSS, it surprises me a week later with more broken renderings.

If there CSS tools or extension you would like me to consider, please share.

Consider me a novice.

Still on ionic 3 :(

Thank you.

```
i
TypeScript version
Version 4.3.5

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.13.1 (C:\Users\AXM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2, browser 5.0.3
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:/Users/AXM/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.9.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

my launch.json profile has "sourceMaps": true
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While testing this in your local environment you would be able to see the references you need (line number and file names) if you leave the source map files in.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#source-maps

*Please note: This is dependent on the rest of your build process. I wouldn't recommend running a minifier or purge tool during development (unless needed) as this can result in issues like yours*

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "if you leave your source file in."?  my launch.json profile has "sourceMaps": true, I don't know where in the build process sass may be invoked with argument --no-source-map, you insights are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I searched all files *.* throughout the source folder for --no-source-map and nothing showed up.